# Variation of the Gauss-Bonnet action and Palatini identity for the purely covariant Riemann tensor

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, curvature, variational-calculus

I'm taking the variation of the Gauss-Bonnet action
$$\mathcal{L}_{GB} = \frac{1}{2}\left(R^{2} - 4R^{\mu\nu}R_{\mu\nu} + R^{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}R_{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}\right)$$
to obtain the equations of motion and the boundary terms. The Equations of motion (E.O.M.) I've end up with are those found in the literature
$$\left[2(RR_{\mu\nu} - 2R^{\alpha\beta}R_{\mu\alpha\nu\beta} - 2R_{\mu}{}^{\alpha}R_{\nu\alpha} + R_{\mu\rho\alpha\beta}R_{\nu}{}^{\rho\alpha\beta}) - \frac{1}{2}g_{\mu\nu}\mathcal{L}_{GB}\right]\delta g^{\mu\nu}.$$
But I'm not sure how to deal with the remaining terms
$$\left(Rg^{\mu\alpha}g^{\nu\beta} - 4R^{\nu\beta}g^{\mu\alpha} + R^{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}\right)\delta R_{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}.$$
My first tought was to make this a total derivative to make it a boundary term (which seems reasonable since I haven't found any article including them in the E.O.M.)... But I can't find a "Palatini Identity" for $\delta R_{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}$.

By this I mean that since
$$
\delta R_{b c d}^{a}=\nabla_{c}\left(\delta \Gamma_{b d}^{a}\right)-\nabla_{d}\left(\delta \Gamma_{b c}^{a}\right)
$$
$$\delta R_{b d}=\nabla_{a}\left(\delta \Gamma_{b d}^{a}\right)-\nabla_{d}\left(\delta \Gamma_{b a}^{a}\right)$$
there might be an equation like
$$\delta R_{\rho\sigma\mu\nu} \overset{?}{=} \nabla_{\mu}\left(\delta\Gamma_{\rho\nu\sigma}\right) - \nabla_{\nu}\left(\delta\Gamma_{\rho\mu\sigma}\right).$$
But I haven't been able to derive such equation. Is there a type of "Palatini identity" for the purely covariant Riemann tensor or any expression that can help me make these terms a total derivative?

Comment: Hi, the expression you're looking for is actually derived in a question & answer in one under the following link: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/126046/. In essence, you're getting an extra term apart from $\delta R^{a}_{bcd}$ because of the one-time-usage of the inverse metric, which also gets varied under $\delta$.

Answer (score 0):

I was also struggling with this, you can have a look at this [http://www.ugr.es/~bjanssen/text/Tesis-JoseAlbertoOrejuela.pdf](http://www.ugr.es/%7Ebjanssen/text/Tesis-JoseAlbertoOrejuela.pdf)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/413287)